# YUV to mp4 conversion

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, h.264

I am using the command:

```
ffmpeg -i MovieTest.yuv -vcodec libx264 -b 1200kb -b_strategy 1 -coder 1 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -me_range 16 -me_method hex -subq 5 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -directpred 1 -flags2 +fastpskip -dts_delta_threshold 1 -acodec libfaac -ab 128kb output.mp4
```

for yuv to mp4 conversion.
Here MovieTest.yuv is my input file and output.mp4 is my output file.
And I am using h.264 codec (libx264) for conversion.

It converts my most of the yuv files properly.
But sometimes, the conversion fails with the error on terminal:

```
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '‪MovieTest.yuv‬':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
  Duration: 00:00:06.45, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 109786 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: rawvideo, uyvy422, 640x480, 109675 kb/s, 22.31 fps, 27.25 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, stereo, s16, 106 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x12180da00]using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0x12180da00]profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x12180da00]264 - core 98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2010 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=6 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x133 me=umh subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=12 keyint_min=7 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=12 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=120 ratetol=33.3 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=10 qpmax=51 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.41 aq=1:1.00
[libfaac @ 0x12180e000]libfaac doesn't support this output format!
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 640x480, q=10-51, 120 kb/s, 90k tbn, 27.25 tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: libfaac, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

If anybody has any idea, that what is going wrong, plz help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your output bit rate (128kb) is higher than your input bit rate (106 kb).

I've just done a quick test and when I put my output higher than my input mine fails with the same errors as yours - it succeeds when I lower it again.

This may explain why it only fails for some inputs.

If you're scripting this in some way you'll have to use either 'ffmpeg -i' or something like [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to analyse your input source first and adjust accordingly.